# Bar Replay "Study references too many candles in history" on Daily Chart and Time Frame

Tags: pine-script

Good Day. I was revisiting a request based script I had been working on months ago and began getting the error "Study references too many candles in history" when trying to use the indicator with daily time setting on a daily chart in bar replay.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0

//@version=5
indicator(title='Currency Raptor Underlay', shorttitle = 'CRU', overlay = false) 
CB1type=syminfo.basecurrency 
CB2type=syminfo.currency
CB1sym1= switch CB1type //Always the Yen Pair
    "USD" => "USDJPY"
    "EUR" => "EURJPY"
    "GBP" => "GBPJPY"
    "CAD" => "CADJPY"
    "AUD" => "AUDJPY"
    "NZD" => "NZDJPY"
    "CHF" => "CHFJPY"
    "JPY" => "JPYUSD"
CB1sym2= switch CB1type 
    "USD" => "USDCAD"
    "EUR" => "EURUSD"
    "GBP" => "GBPUSD"
    "CAD" => "CADUSD"
    "AUD" => "AUDUSD"
    "NZD" => "NZDUSD"
    "CHF" => "CHFUSD"
    "JPY" => "JPYAUD"
CB1sym3= switch CB1type 
    "USD" => "USDEUR"
    "EUR" => "EURAUD"
    "GBP" => "GBPAUD"
    "CAD" => "CADAUD"
    "AUD" => "AUDCAD"
    "NZD" => "NZDAUD"
    "CHF" => "CHFAUD"
    "JPY" => "JPYCAD"
CB1sym4= switch CB1type 
    "USD" => "USDGBP"
    "EUR" => "EURCAD"
    "GBP" => "GBPCAD"
    "CAD" => "CADNZD"
    "AUD" => "AUDNZD"
    "NZD" => "NZDCAD"
    "CHF" => "CHFNZD"
    "JPY" => "JPYNZD"
CB1sym5= switch CB1type 
    "USD" => "USDAUD"
    "EUR" => "EURNZD"
    "GBP" => "GBPNZD"
    "CAD" => "CADCHF"
    "AUD" => "AUDGBP"
    "NZD" => "NZDGBP"
    "CHF" => "CHFGBP"
    "JPY" => "JPYCHF"
CB1sym6= switch CB1type 
    "USD" => "USDNZD"
    "EUR" => "EURCHF"
    "GBP" => "GBPCHF"
    "CAD" => "CADGBP"
    "AUD" => "AUDEUR"
    "NZD" => "NZDEUR"
    "CHF" => "CHFEUR"
    "JPY" => "JPYEUR"
CB1sym7= switch CB1type 
    "USD" => "USDCHF"
    "EUR" => "EURGBP"
    "GBP" => "GBPEUR"
    "CAD" => "CADEUR"
    "AUD" => "AUDCHF"
    "NZD" => "NZDCHF"
    "CHF" => "CHFCAD"
    "JPY" => "JPYGBP"
//Begin Second Basket
CB2sym1= switch CB2type //Always the Yen Pair
    "USD" => "USDJPY"
    "EUR" => "EURJPY"
    "GBP" => "GBPJPY"
    "CAD" => "CADJPY"
    "AUD" => "AUDJPY"
    "NZD" => "NZDJPY"
    "CHF" => "CHFJPY"
    "JPY" => "JPYUSD"
CB2sym2= switch CB2type 
    "USD" => "USDCAD"
    "EUR" => "EURUSD"
    "GBP" => "GBPUSD"
    "CAD" => "CADUSD"
    "AUD" => "AUDUSD"
    "NZD" => "NZDUSD"
    "CHF" => "CHFUSD"
    "JPY" => "JPYAUD"
CB2sym3= switch CB2type 
    "USD" => "USDEUR"
    "EUR" => "EURAUD"
    "GBP" => "GBPAUD"
    "CAD" => "CADAUD"
    "AUD" => "AUDCAD"
    "NZD" => "NZDAUD"
    "CHF" => "CHFAUD"
    "JPY" => "JPYCAD"
CB2sym4= switch CB2type 
    "USD" => "USDGBP"
    "EUR" => "EURCAD"
    "GBP" => "GBPCAD"
    "CAD" => "CADNZD"
    "AUD" => "AUDNZD"
    "NZD" => "NZDCAD"
    "CHF" => "CHFNZD"
    "JPY" => "JPYNZD"
CB2sym5= switch CB2type 
    "USD" => "USDAUD"
    "EUR" => "EURNZD"
    "GBP" => "GBPNZD"
    "CAD" => "CADCHF"
    "AUD" => "AUDGBP"
    "NZD" => "NZDGBP"
    "CHF" => "CHFGBP"
    "JPY" => "JPYCHF"
CB2sym6= switch CB2type 
    "USD" => "USDNZD"
    "EUR" => "EURCHF"
    "GBP" => "GBPCHF"
    "CAD" => "CADGBP"
    "AUD" => "AUDEUR"
    "NZD" => "NZDEUR"
    "CHF" => "CHFEUR"
    "JPY" => "JPYEUR"
CB2sym7= switch CB2type 
    "USD" => "USDCHF"
    "EUR" => "EURGBP"
    "GBP" => "GBPEUR"
    "CAD" => "CADEUR"
    "AUD" => "AUDCHF"
    "NZD" => "NZDCHF"
    "CHF" => "CHFCAD"
    "JPY" => "JPYGBP"
// Begin Requests 
rsrc=input.source(defval = hlc3,title = 'Raptor Source')
rwindow=input.timeframe(defval = 'D', title = 'Raptor Timeframe') 
//First Basket 
r1= request.security(CB1sym1, rwindow, rsrc/100)
r2=CB1type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB1sym2, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB1sym2, rwindow, rsrc)
r3=CB1type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB1sym3, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB1sym3, rwindow, rsrc)
r4= CB1type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB1sym4, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB1sym4, rwindow, rsrc)
r5= CB1type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB1sym5, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB1sym5, rwindow, rsrc)
r6= CB1type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB1sym6, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB1sym6, rwindow, rsrc)
r7= CB1type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB1sym7, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB1sym7, rwindow, rsrc)
R1Bclose= (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7)/7

//Second Basket
r11= request.security(CB2sym1, rwindow, rsrc/100)
r12=CB2type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB2sym2, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB2sym2, rwindow, rsrc)
r13=CB2type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB2sym3, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB2sym3, rwindow, rsrc)
r14= CB2type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB2sym4, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB2sym4, rwindow, rsrc)
r15= CB2type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB2sym5, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB2sym5, rwindow, rsrc)
r16= CB2type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB2sym6, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB2sym6, rwindow, rsrc)
r17= CB2type=="JPY" ? request.security(CB2sym7, rwindow, rsrc)/100: request.security(CB2sym7, rwindow, rsrc)
R2Bclose= (r11+r12+r13+r14+r15+r16+r17)/7

//1st PPO Settings
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=3)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=7)
src1 = R1Bclose
src2 = R2Bclose
fast_ma1 = ta.sma(src1, fast_length)
slow_ma1 = ta.sma(src1, slow_length)
fast_length2 = fast_length
slow_length2 = slow_length
fast_ma2 = ta.sma(src2, fast_length)
slow_ma2 = ta.sma(src2, slow_length)
ppo1 = (fast_ma1 - slow_ma1) / slow_ma1 * 100
ppo2 = (fast_ma2 - slow_ma2) / slow_ma2 * 100 



//plot(ppo2, title="2nd PPO", color=bull or bear? color.yellow: color.orange, linewidth = 3)
hline(0,title = 'Zero Line', color = color.white, linestyle = hline.style_dashed)

hist = ppo1-ppo2
//PLOTS
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color = hist>0? color.blue: color.red)
```

When viewing on a weekly chart or intraday, the settings can go between timeframes without issues. I can partially bypass the error by making a custom timeframe for 24 hours and passing that through the time input on a daily chart, but the output repaints a small difference from when viewing the script outside of bar replay on the daily chart.